# Why variable username and password not saving in the variable user and pass to how data in popup staffInfoController?

Tags: java, javafx

Why variable `user` and `pass` not saving in the variable `user` and `pass` to show data in popup:
`staffInfo.fxml` ?

Which I think that variable from `user` and `pass` supposed to be read in `StaffInfoController.java`.

*StaffInfoController.java*

```java
package Controller;

import static Controller.HomeController.user;
import static Controller.HomeController.pass;
import Entitas.Pegawai;
import DBHelper.DBHelper;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class StaffInfoController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label lblGaji;

    @FXML
    private Label lblIdPegawai;

    @FXML
    private Label lblJabatan;

    @FXML
    private Label lblNama;

    @FXML
    private Label lblStatus;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rc) {
        try {
            showBiodata();
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StaffInfoController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void showBiodata() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = DBHelper.getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM pegawai WHERE username = '" + user + "' AND password_pegawai = '" + pass + "'";
        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs;
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        if (rs.next()) {
            lblGaji.setText(String.format("%d", rs.getLong("gaji")));
            lblIdPegawai.setText(rs.getString("id_pegawai"));
            lblJabatan.setText(rs.getString("jabatan"));
            lblNama.setText(rs.getString("nama_pegawai"));
            lblStatus.setText(rs.getString("status_pegawai"));
        }
    }
}
```

*HomeController.java*

```java
package Controller;

import DBHelper.DBHelper;
import AlertHelper.AlertHelper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HomeController {

    @FXML
    private Hyperlink btnBuatAkun;

    @FXML
    private Button btnLogin;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField pfPassword;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfUsername;

    public static String user;
    public static String pass;

    @FXML
    public void gantiScene(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        user = tfUsername.getText();
        pass = pfPassword.getText();
        if (validateLogin(user, pass, "pegawai")) {
            AlertHelper.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION,
                                  "Login berhasil",
                                  "Login Pegawai Telah Berhasil");
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FXMLCol/Pegawai.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            Stage stage = (Stage) btnLogin.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        }
        else if (validateLogin(user, pass, "pelanggan")) {
            AlertHelper.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION,
                                  "Login Berhasil",
                                  "Login Username : " + user + " berhasil");
        }
        else {
            AlertHelper.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR,
                                  "Login Gagal",
                                  "Silahkan check username dan password lebih teliti");
            pfPassword.clear();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void keBuatAkun(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        AlertHelper.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING,
                              "Konfirmasi",
                              " Anda akan dialihkan ke arah pembuatan akun");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FXMLCol/Pegawai.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Stage stage = (Stage) btnBuatAkun.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    }

    public static boolean validateLogin(String username, String password, String entitas) {
        String query;
        if (entitas.equals("pelanggan")) {
            query = "SELECT * FROM `pelanggan` WHERE username = ?  AND password_pelanggan = ? ";
        }
        else {
            query = "SELECT * FROM `pegawai` WHERE username = ?  AND password_pegawai = ? ";
        }
        try (Connection connection = DBHelper.getConnection()) {
            try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
                preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
                try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
                    return resultSet.next();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[output staffInfo.fxml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Xib.png)

Can you all help me?

Literally in that stage is not showing the Staff Information.

Anything solution with that problem?

Comment: Are you referring to this line of your code? `String sql = "SELECT * FROM pegawai WHERE username = '"+ user + "' AND password_pegawai = '" + pass +"'" ;` Pardon me, but I don't see where variables `user` and `pass` are assigned values. I suggest that you try to post a [mcve]. Remember, we don't have your database, so post hard-coded values rather than values returned by a SQL query.

Comment: Not really related to your problem, nonetheless, note that controller classes no longer need to implement interface [Initializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html). You should write a `void initialize()` method, i.e. a method named `initialize` that takes no parameters and does not return a value. This method is invoked via [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) by the JavaFX infrastructure.

Answer (score 2):

Use this method to create a mighty alert dialog and pass arguments with ease via a method:

**Helper method:**

```
public static Stage createFxmlDialog(
        String title,
        boolean dialogIsModal,
        boolean dialogIsResizeable,
        URL absoluteFxmlFileUrl,
        Dimension2D sceneSize,
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Consumer initMethodOfController,
        Runnable callbackOnDialogClose)
        throws IOException {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(absoluteFxmlFileUrl);
    Parent root = loader.load(); // this calls the constructor and after that initialize from jfx()
    Object viewController = loader.getController();
    Scene scene = sceneSize == null ? new Scene(root) : new Scene(root, sceneSize.getWidth(), sceneSize.getHeight());

    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle(title);
    stage.initModality(dialogIsModal ? Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL : Modality.NONE);
    stage.setResizable(dialogIsResizeable);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setOnHidden(event -> {
        event.consume();
        if (callbackOnDialogClose != null) {
            callbackOnDialogClose.run();
        }
        stage.close();
    });

    if (initMethodOfController != null) {
        //noinspection unchecked
        initMethodOfController.accept(viewController);
    }
    return stage;
}
```

**In new Controller:**

Create a method:

`public void init(String username){ this.username = username; }`

**How to call:**

```
    createAndShowFxmlDialog(
            "Dialogtitle",
            true,
            false,
            getClass().getResource("/com/abc/scene.fxml"),
            null,
            (Consumer<ControllerOfFxml>) consumer -> consumer.init("myparamter1"),
            null).showAndWait();
```

**Additional infos:**

This code is taken from my personal framework. You can take a look into `JfxDialogUtil` for more informations.

https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-SimpleJavaFxApplicationBase

PS: You can give me a star on GitHub for appreciation if you want. :D